# Visual glitch in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I'm experiencing a visual glitch in SSMS. Whenever I hide the results pane, the editor is covered in dark, as is the application was not repainted correctly. It would look like a graphic card/driver issue but it's only happening with ssms (all the time) and sometimes with visual studio. It happens even immediately after rebooting, with no other programs running, so it's not a low RAM issue.

Already tried updating ssms, and then a complete uninstall.
Also tried upgrading visual studio from 2015 to 2017.

The glitch also appears if I move downwards the horizontal bar that separates the editor from the results pane.

The glitch disappears if I move upwards the horizontal bar that separates the editor from the Results pane, or if I restore/maximize the ssms window, or if I move the vertical bar that separates the editor from the Object Explorer.

Haven't found anyone with this problem, googling around. Any idea on how to solve this? It's driving me nuts.

I'm including a screenshot of the glitch:
[screenshot of SSMS after pressing Ctrl+R to hide the Results pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw66G.jpg)

Comment: This could potentially be an issue with your video card and/or video card driver. Try updating the driver, rebooting, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to comment. This happens even if I open ssms immediately after rebooting. Drivers are up to date.

Comment: I just started seeing this issue on a newly installed Windows 10 machine. Like the OP all drivers and patches have been installed. The video card I am using is an RTX2070 and I had this card running for a month or so in another machine with the same drivers and did not experience this.

Does anyone else have some suggestions?